# Zend Framework: How to retrieve the id of the last inserted row?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db, zend-db-table

I'm inserting a new row into my database with this code:

```
$data = array(
    'key' => 'value'
);
$this->getDbTable()->insert($data);
```

How can I get the row id of the this row that I just created?

Answer (score 16):

Did you try this ? This also works fine.

```
//just after you call your insert($data) function .. use this
$lastInsertId = $this->getAdapter()->lastInsertId();
```

Answer (score 10):

One gotcha. When calling `$this->getDbTable()->insert($data);` you have to make sure $data include the "primary key" of your table. For example, `id=null` if it's auto-increment. Otherwise, `insert()` will not return the last inserted ID.

Comment: One note, this is already marked as fixed in v1.11.6. See http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-3837

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

To insert data:

```
$this->tableGateway->insert($data);
```

Get Last Inserted value:

```
$this->tableGateway->lastInsertValue;
```

Comment: what if another user inserted a record after, the lastInsertValue would get the last inserted id in general or for the certain transaction -if used-?

Answer (score 0):

There is also `newId` function, witch returns the next new ID, so you can use it to insert a new row.

```
$id = $this->getDbTable->newId('table_name', 'id');

$data = array(
    'id' => $id,
    'data' => $data
);

$this->getDbTable->insertRow('table_name', $data);
```

Now you can do whatever you want with your `$id`.