# how to get last inserted id - zend

Tags: sql, zend-framework

I'm trying to get latest inserted id from a table using this code:

```
$id = $tbl->fetchAll (array('public=1'), 'id desc');
```

but it's always returning "1"

any ideas?

---

**update:** I've just discovered toArray();, which retrieves all the data from fetchAll. The problem is, I only need the ID. My current code looks like this:

```
$rowsetArray = $id->toArray();
$rowCount = 1;

foreach ($rowsetArray as $rowArray) {
    foreach ($rowArray as $column => $value) {
       if ($column="id") {$myid[$brr] = $value;}
      //echo"\n$myid[$brr]";
    }
    ++$rowCount;
    ++$brr;
}
```

Obviously, I've got the `if ($column="id") {$myid[$brr] = $value;}` thing wrong.
Can anyone point me in the right direction?

An aternative would be to filter ID's from fetchAll. Is that possible?

Comment: maybe a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1868769/zend-framework-how-to-retrieve-the-id-of-the-last-inserted-row ?

Comment: it's not the same, because I'm not using it after inserting new row

Comment: to clarify this further, I need to get ID's of articles that are published (hence 'public=1'), so I can write links to most recent articles.

Answer (score 1):

Think you can use:

```
$id = $tbl->lastInsertId();
```

Comment: It returns undefined function error, probably because I'm not using it after insert.

Answer (score 1):

Aren't you trying to get last INSERT id from SELECT query?

Use lastInsertId() or the value returned by insert: $id = $db->insert();

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using `fetchAll()` to retrieve the last inserted ID? `fetchAll()` will return a rowset of results (multiple records) as an object (not an array, but can be converted into an array using the `toArray()` method). However, if you are trying to reuse a rowset you already have, and you know the last record is the first record in the rowset, you can do this:

```
$select = $table->select()
    ->where('public = 1')
    ->order('id DESC');
$rows = $table->fetchAll($select);
$firstRow = $rows->current();
$lastId = $firstRow->id;
```

If you were to use `fetchRow()`, it would return a single row, so you wouldn't have to call `current()` on the result:

```
$select = $table->select()
    ->where('public = 1')
    ->order('id DESC');
$row = $table->fetchRow($select);
$lastId = $row->id;
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like it's returning true rather than the actual value. Check the return value for the function fetchAll

Comment: according to http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php, fetchAll should return an array.. maybe I'm getting something wrong