# Insert in Foreach PHP

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have PHP:

```
if($post['for']){
    foreach($post['for'] as $value){
        $saveMsgObjFor->message_id = $save;
        $saveMsgObjFor->object_type_id = 4;
        $saveMsgObjFor->object_ref_id = $value;
        $saveMsgObjFor->object_email = null;
        $saveMsgObjFor->save($update);
    }
}
```

But it just save first loop. For twice, it show error:

```
Statement could not be executed (23000 - 1062 - Duplicate entry
 '33' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

`33` is field `message_object_id` and it was `auto increment`. Help me, please..

Comment: Thanks, it worked! Would make it as answer so i can accept it @KenY-N

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the [hint in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3128398/1270789), it would appear that you need to explicitly set the `message_object_id` to `null`. First time round it defaults to `null`, but then after the `save()` it gets set to the `auto increment` value, so you need to explicitly reset it, for example:

```
foreach($post['for'] as $value){
    $saveMsgObjFor->message_object_id = null;
    $saveMsgObjFor->message_id = $save;
```

Answer (score 0):

I presume you should remove the following line from your code:

```
$saveMsgObjFor->message_id = $save;
```

I'm not overly familiar with the Zend framework but it looks like you're trying to assign the same value to a auto_increment, which won't work, as it's the row's identifier and must be unique. Hope this helps!